# Is VBA functions available from Delphi?

Tags: excel, vba, delphi, com

I know that I can always get Excel COM objects (reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)) in Delphi from the Variant variable:

```
var Excel: Variant;
Excel:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
```

But is it possible to access VBA functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/functions-visual-basic-for-applications from Delphi somehow? E.g. I am interested in `TypeName` to use it for `TypeName(Excel.Selection)`.

Also, it is interesting, that Delphi shows $00000000 for the `Excel.Selection` and futher access of Cells, Rows, etc. on the `Excel.Selection` gives access violation.

I would not like to import Excel type library in my project, because I would like my application to be agnostic to the specific Excel version.

Comment: `TypeName` and other VBA functions are not a part of Excel object model.

Comment: Importing Excel type library does not tie your application to a specific version.

Comment: You don't say you want to access VBA code, but have you looked at whether the Windows Scripting Host (WSH) could execute the code you're interested in?  You can automate WSH from a Delphi app.